# Ubuntu not booting in recovery mode

Tags: scripts

As suggested by others to boot the system in recovery mode I bend down the shift key but the system still just starts up normally.

Comment: I take it you press and hold the shift key? If you use a USB keyboard, try swapping keyboards, that sometimes (albeit rarely) helps (apparently there are issues with some USB keyboards).

Comment: you can use grub-customizer to force grub to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UEFI, you need to press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on system startup instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>. If that doesn't work, try one of the alternatives below.

### If you can still boot into ubuntu:

Open `/etc/default/grub` as root, e.g.:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change the following lines accordingly:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
```

Save and exit (if using nano, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the filename).

Now run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. The grub menu should be shown now without pressing a key.

### If you can't boot into ubuntu, but can boot a live session (e.g. from a live USB drive):

After booting the live system, open nautilus (the file manager), click on "Other Locations" and select your internal drive. Now open a terminal and run

```
sudo nano /media/ubuntu/<UUID>/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Where `<UUID>` is the UUID of the partition. I recommend using <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion, i.e. after entering `/media/ubuntu/`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the UUID.

Now change the following lines accordingly:

```
set timeout_style=menu
set timeout=-1
```

(Those lines appear before `### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###`).

Save and exit (if using nano, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the filename).

Reboot.